# I need to download images referenced in the href attribute of anchors using Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, getattribute

Retrieved links should be obtained in a sequential fashion in order to allow further processing. This is what I've tryied til now:

```py
lay = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div')
fig = lay.find_elements_by_class_name('_2Mc8_')

for link in fig:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    print href
    for ab in href:   
        ab = driver.get(href)
        dwn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[3]/a/span')
        dwn.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: You can download images using ```urllib.urlretrieve``` just give the source url for the image.

Comment: i have multiple images, i cant locate the url which can be common for all

Comment: Can you show me the page you are scrapping?

Comment: https://unsplash.com/photos/aPoDEueaJvY   similar links to be opened and Good Quality to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lay = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//')
fig = lay.find_elements_by_class_name('_2Mc8_')

for link in fig:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    print href
    for ab in href:   
        driver.get(ab)
        dwn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//')
        dwn.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a project like this a while ago. What you want to do is open a kind of stream and download the object to that stream and then close it again.

```
def requests_image(file_url):
    i = requests.get(file_url)
    if i.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        #save the file as a temporary name. Note that this is a static name, so I won't be able to run two threads at the same time.
        with iopen("images/TEMP_file_name", 'wb') as file:
            file.write(i.content)
            #this is to get the correct extension of the file. Handy when you can't derive it from the URL.
            ext = imghdr.what("images/TEMP_file_name")
            file.close()
            uidname = str(int(time.time()))[-8:]
            ##Create unique filename using UNIXTIME[-8:] (last 8 chars of unixtime in S)
            filename = uidname+"."+ext
            #Now that the stream is closed, rename it from the static name to a unique name. I chose to use time since epoch. Add the extension and you're good to go.
            os.rename("images/TEMP_file_name", "images/"+filename)
            return(filename)
    else:
        return False
```

above is the function I'd use. To call it simply do:

```
fname = requests_image(href)
if fname: #truthy statement
    pass #if you have a succesfull file returned it might be needed to store it in a database. use the fname variable for this.
else:
    pass# if the filename returns false (might be if the link turns out to be invalid) log it and investigate if it's essential to know.
```